# (Why) did God take away free will from the sons of Eli?

Tags: theology, sin, repentance-teshuvah, samuel-shmuel-book-of

In 1 Shmuel 2:25 it indicates that the sons of Eli don't repent for their sins because God wanted to kill them

> וְלֹ֤א יִשְׁמְעוּ֙ לְק֣וֹל אֲבִיהֶ֔ם כִּֽי־חָפֵ֥ץ ה' לַהֲמִיתָֽם
> But [the sons of Eli] ignored their father’s plea; for the LORD was resolved that they should die.

Chazal and many commentators (eg Malbim) read this as a removal of free will. If that is the case I would like to understand the following

1. What did they do differently than any other sinner to have their free will removed?
2. Why would Eli be told (twice) that they would be punished if there is nothing he can do about it?
3. How do we understand theologically that God "wants" to kill someone (rather than seeing that person repent)?

Comment: Related: Rabbeinu Bahya (sv. ואיך אעשה הרעה הגדולה הזאת וחטאתי לאלהים)

Comment: My understanding from the Rambam, Mishnah Torah laws of repentance, there’s a certain point where God withdraws free will from sinners.  This supposedly happened to Egypt

Comment: 1. What did they do differently than any other sinner to have their free will removed? - They made a *chilul Hashem*.